# How to avoid the issue of not being able to instantiate an abstract class

Tags: c++

I have the following problem working with a library (it is the [hdf5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/) library, but it doesn't matter).
I would like to do something like the following, but I think I can't because the Base class is abstract. In other words, I can't have late binding because I can't instantiate an object of an abstract class.

I have an abstract class and 2 derived classes. The code of main() is not correct because I can't do Base theObject;

```
//An abstract class
class Base
{
protected:
    Base() {}
public:
    void doSomething() = 0;
};

class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedA() : Base() {}
    void doSomething() {cout << "I am a DerivedA" << endl;}
};

class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedB() : Base() {}
    void doSomething() {cout << "I am a DerivedB" << endl;}
};


int main()
{
    // A special function returns the type of object that it is placed at "thePath".  
    int theType = someSpecialFunction(thePath);
    Base theObject;   //This is not possible.
    switch (theType)
    {
        case 1: //A derivedA object
        {
             theObject = openObjectOfTypeA(thePath); //Special function of the library.            
             break;
        }
        case 2: //A derivedB object
        {
             theObject = openObjectOfTypeB(thePath); //Special function of the library
             break;
        }
    }

    theObject.doSomething();
    //whatever
}
```

I can do something like the following. However, in a real scenario I would end with a lot of repeated code.

```
int main()
{
    // A special function returns the type of object that it is placed at "thePath"
    int theType = someSpecialFunction(thePath);
    switch (theType)
    {
        case 1: //A derivedA object
        {
             DerivedA theObject = openObjectOfTypeA(thePath);
             theObject.doSomething();
             break;
        }
        case 2: //A derivedB object
        {
             DerivedB theObject = openObjectOfTypeB(thePath);
             theObject.doSomething();
             break;
        }
    }
    //whatever
}
```

Is there any method to avoid my "solution"?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you cant have instances, but you can have pointers, you could use a `Base* theObject`. Anyhow `Base theObject = DerivedA();` is broken (indpendent of `Base` being abstract) due to object slicing

Comment: Languages provide polymorphism so that you don't have to dispatch on type & downcast.

Comment: @tobi303 Regarding the object slicing problem. If I am using only the pointer Base * theObject to call doSomething(), there is no problem right?

Comment: no with pointers there is no slicing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have

`Base* theObject;`

And use the pointer to call member function . You will have to change return type of `openObjectOfTypeA/B` to return a pointer to `Base` class.

`theObject->doSomething();`

Comment: I can't change the functions openObjecOfTypeA/B (they are part of a library). Hence, I will have to do something like: `DerivedA tmpObj = openObjectOfTypeA(thePath); theObject = &tmpObj;` And after the switch `theObject->doSomething`. Right? Thank you so much. Is there any danger with this method?

Comment: @pablo_worker `theObject` pointer should point to a valid address, make sure you don't dereference something that doesn't hold a valid address. The `tmpObj` can go out of scope, which you will have to take care of. Also its nice to assign `Base *theObject = nullptr;` So you can always check for `nullptr` before dereferencing it.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.

Comment: @pablo_worker You have to be carefull with  `&tmpObj;`. if you create the  `tmpObj` inside of the switch statement your pointer will be invalid after the switch. So that is what P0W meand here. the moment `tmpObj` dies `theObject` will be invalid and you cannot catch this specific error by checking `theObject` against `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Only virtual methods in a base class can be abstract, so your first class should have protyped doSomething as this:

virtual void doSomething() = 0;

You can get around using a "type" parameter by using pointers. A pointer to a base class (e.g. Base) can point to any derived class (e.g. DerivedA or DerivedB). Then, when you wish to call doSomething(), it will call the doSomething of the child class.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap this in a factory function.

```
std::unique<Base> getObject( ... thePath)
{
    const int theType = someSpecialFunction(thePath);
    switch (theType)
    {
        case 1: //A derivedA object
            return std::make_unique<DerivedA>(openObjectOfTypeA(thePath));
        case 2: //A derivedB object
            return std::make_unique<DerivedB>(openObjectOfTypeB(thePath));
    }
    return nullptr;
}


//...     
std::unique<Base> basePtr = getObject(path);
basePtr->doSomething();
//...
```

If you don't have c++14 available you can replace the `unique_ptr` with boost `shared_ptr` or raw pointer.